# Confusion with dimension of cartesian vs tensor product

Tags: linear-transformations, tensors

I learned that given a vector space $V$, you can make a dual vector space $V^*$, which is the space of the linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Both spaces have the same dimension D.

If we define the Cartesian product $V \times V$, then we can define the tensor space $V^* \times V^*$, which is the space of the linear maps from $V \times V$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Question: Is $V^* \times V^*$ the dual of $V \times V$? It seems it is not, because the dimension of $V^* \times V^*$ is $D^2$, but the dimension of $V \times V$ is 2D. So, why aren't they duals? or are they and I said something wrong?

Note: One comments mentions that the issue is related to bilinear vs linear map. I am not sure to understand why or how, so if that is the case please be give me a little more of detail. Thanks.

### Note 2:

This professor defined $V^* \times V^*$ as $(V \times V)^*$, that is, the dual space of the cartesian product of V with itself. By dual I mean the set of linear transformations from $V \times V$ to the reals.

Now, it clear that $V \times V$ has dimension 2D, where D is the dimension of V. What is the dimension of the above defined $V^* \times V^*$? He said one base is the set of linear transformations satisfying $(e_i, e_j)=\delta_{ij}$, but this base has dimension $D^2$, right? He also uses the dual to define tensors, which also makes me think the dimension is $D^2$. So I am still confused. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is. Both of them have dimension $2D$. Neither of them, as written, is a tensor product.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But isnt $e^i$x$e^j$ a basis for $V^*$x$V^*$

Comment: No, it's not, that would be the tensor product.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan oh, I might have totally misunderstood what the professor explained

Comment: I got it from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SjJEmSqFh0. He seems like a guy who knows what he is talking about

Comment: That video uses $V \times V$ to define *bilinear* maps. Here $V \times V$ is just the cartesian product as sets, not the cartesian product as vector spaces. A bilinear map $V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ corresponds to a linear map $V \otimes V \to \mathbb{R}$. It does *not* correspond to a linear map $V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, I will look into that

Comment: there are two vectorspaces constructed out from $V$: the direct sum $V\oplus V$ with dimension $2D$ and the tensor product $V\otimes V$ of dimension $D^2$

Answer (score 2):

When we talk about a vector space $V$, we talk about both the set itself and its operations.

> Question: Is $V^∗ \times V^∗$ the dual of $V \times V$?

The set $V^* \times V^*%$ contains all elements in the shape of $(f, f')$ where $f, f' \in V^*$. Since you only need to determine where the basis maps to in order to determine a linear map, we have the basis
$\{f_i\}$ for $V^*$ where $f_i$ maps the $i$st basis of $V$, $v_i$ to $1$ and maps other $v_j$ to $0$. The basis for $V^*$ has a length $D$.

Hence we have the basis $\{(f_i,\mathbf{0})\} \cup \{(\mathbf{0}, f_i)\}$ for $V^* \times V^*$ as a vector space. The basis has a length $2D$.

The dual of $V \times V$ contains all the linear map from $V \times V$ to its field $\mathbb{F}$, which has the basis $\{g_i\} \cup \{g'_i\}$, each $g_i$ maps $(v_i,\mathbf{0})$ to $1$ and each $g'_i$ maps $(\mathbf{0}, v_i)$ to $1$. The basis also has a length $2D$.

Note that the elements in $V^* \times V^*$ are a pair of linear maps, while the dual of $V \times V$ is a linear map that maps a pair of vectors in $V$. So they appear not to be the same at first, but you can treat them the same way.

If you are asking for $V^* \otimes V^*$, they do have dimension of $D^2$, and so does the dual of $V \otimes V$.

Comment: p l u s 10 . . .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wrote NOTE 2 at the bottom of my question because your answer is still not helpful (may be my confusion is too big). Thanks

Comment: I will give you the bounty so that the points do not get wasted, but I would appreciate if you can answer my question. Thanks again!

Comment: @brucesmitherson What is $e_i$ in your notation? I don't quite understand your notation.

Answer (score 1):

With the comments aiding to focus, the statement what
you are looking is the dual of $V\oplus V$ is $V^*\oplus V^*$, that is
$$(V\oplus V)^*\cong V^*\oplus V^*$$

This, also helps us not to involve with the tensor product.

Comment: the answer of my rival  : ) is a detailed explain

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wrote NOTE 2 at the bottom of my question because your answer is still not helpful (may be my confusion is too big). Thanks

Comment: Actually you did answer part of it, my doubt now would be why the dimension of $(V\oplus V)^*\cong V^*\oplus V^*$ seems to be $D^2$ rather than 2D, or is that a mistake or slight of hands that our professor made? What I mean is that he seems to start with V+V and seems to end up with $V^*xV^*$

Comment: there is a set $V\times V$ on which one define the sum of vector as $$(u,w)+(s,t)=(u+s,v+t),$$ and scalar action as $$k(u,v)=(ku,kv)$$  to convert $V\times V$ into vector space, this is the direct sum $V\oplus V$ and has dimension $2D$. The details was given by Lab.

Comment: Yes, that is what he did, but the dual seems to have dimension D^2. What is "Lab"?

Comment: the other guy answering, who won the bounty

Comment: You sound bitter that I gave him the bounty. That is silly. I will post another bounty and will give it to you if you help me figure this out. I will give you 200 points.

Comment: I just realized the person who gave the other answer was named Lab, lol. What I mean by "him" is the professor who gave the class. Please read note 2

Comment: Watch: if $V$ would be generated by $e_1,e_2$ then $V^*$ should be generated by $f^1,f^2$ such that $$f^i(e_j)=\delta^i_j,$$ then a basis for $V\times V$ is generated by $\{(e_1,0),(e_2,0), (0,e_1), (0,e_2)\}$ but for $V^*\times V^*$ is generated by $\{(f^1,0),(f^2,0), (0,f^1), (0,f^2)\}$

Comment: beware here because $2D=D^2=4$ : )

Comment: @brucesmitherson, just to here, are you already understanding  all?

Comment: No, I am sorry, I could not work on this on the last few days. I will be back later tonight, to have a chance to ask and get a last comment from you. Thanks!

Comment: Well, what you have to take into account is that there are 3 things involved: 1. The set $V\times V$ is only a set, 2. The set $V\times V$ with the operation direct sum is the vectorspace $V\oplus V$, 3. Based on the set $V\times V$, the free vectorspace $F$ over it and a subspace $R$, it is  tensor product $V\otimes V$ the quotient space $F/R$. The exact content of $R$ makes it incorporate *bi-linearity* with that tensor.